# Google Map marker colors based on csv table values

Tags: csv, colors, maps, google-maps-markers

I have code that works for displaying individuals of a group across the world. I would like to have the color of each marker to reflect a color based on a value in the CSV data. I have tried multiple ideas and cannot figure it out.

The CSV file contains 12 different colors in the lost, all 2 word inputs. I would like to have the pin color be blue for each marker color that equals "something 1", then red for each marker color that equals "something 2".

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var marker = {};
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        center: { lat: 39.8, lng: -89.5},
        zoom: 4
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
    var markers = [];
    <?php 
        $counter = 0;
        foreach ($markers as $index => $list){
               $marker_details = explode(',',$list);
               echo 'markers["m'.($index-1).'"] = {};'."\n";
               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].lat = '".$marker_details[4]."';\n";
               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].lon = '".$marker_details[5]."';\n";
               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].name = '".$marker_details[0]."';\n";
               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].handle = '".$marker_details[1]."';\n";
               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].city = '".$marker_details[2]."';\n";
                               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].state = '".$marker_details[3]."';\n";
                               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].phone = '".$marker_details[6]."';\n";
                               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].email = '".$marker_details[7]."';\n"; 
                               echo "markers['m".($index-1)."'].color = '".$marker_details[8]."';\n";
               $counter++;
       }
    ?>
    var totalMarkers = <?=$counter?>;
    var i = 0;
    var infowindow;
    var contentString;
    for (var i = 0; i<totalMarkers; i++){
        
        contentString = '<div class="content">'+
              '<h3 class="firstHeading">Handle - '+markers['m'+i].handle+'</h3>'+
              '<div class="bodyContent">'+
              '<p>Name - '+markers['m'+i].name+'</p>'+
                              '<p>City - '+markers['m'+i].city+'</p>'+
                              '<p>State - '+markers['m'+i].state+'</p>'+
                              '<p>Phone - '+markers['m'+i].phone+'</p>'+
                              '<p>Email - '+markers['m'+i].email+'</p>'+
                              '<p>Truck Color - '+markers['m'+i].color+'</p>'+
              '</div>'+
              '</div>';
        
        
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              content: contentString
        });

        marker['c'+i] = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markers['m'+i].lat,markers['m'+i].lon),
                map: map,
                title: markers['m'+i].handle,
                infowindow: infowindow
          });
        //console.log(markers['m'+i].lat+','+markers['m'+i].lon);
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker['c'+i], 'click', function() {
                for (var key in marker){
                    marker[key].infowindow.close();
                }
                this.infowindow.open(map, this);
                
        });
    }

  }
  function panMap(la,lo){
        map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(la,lo));
        
  }
  function openMarker(mName){
      //console.log(marker);
      for (var key in marker){
          marker[key].infowindow.close();
      }
      for (var key in marker){
          
        if (marker[key].title.search(mName) != -1){
            marker[key].infowindow.open(map,marker[key]);
        }
      }
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I am not a coder or very familiar with programming. I took parts from working scripts and ideas I had to get things working to this point. The map works well but having colored markers for the colors listed in the CSV file is something I have tried to do from the beginning (several years) and have failed at every attempt. Any help is appreciated......